# JPA Hibernate, Lazy loading after a Join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to get a entity and its collection from a Rest controler but I have a very strange behaviour with spring data JPA.

I have a ManyToMany relation beetween to entities with a Lazy loading.

```
@Entity
class Folder{
    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Set<Tag> tags;

    ...getter setter
}

@Entity class Tag{

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tags"
    protected List<File> files; 
}
```

And a JPQL query in a spring jpa repository

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Folder f INNER JOIN f.tags t WHERE
        f.id = :id")
Folder findFolderById(@Param("id") int id);
```

So the Folder is supposed to be populated with the Tag collection and avoid the lazy loading part.

But I can see in the logs that after the Join Query 
there is a select on the Tag table, so a lazy loading.

Hibernate: select folder0_.id as id2_2_...
Hibernate: select tags0_.files_id ...

I don't want to use fetch type EAGER because I don't always need the Tag collection. How can I avoid that Lazy loading ?

Comment: Specify a fetch join: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins

Comment: what I read in oracles example is this: the query returns 5 references to the mag azinewith id 1 . Why is this useful?

Comment: @JimHawkins  it means that if you have a oneToMany relationship between  Magazine and Article, the JPA implementation will populate your Magazine objects and their collections of Article with one query. If you don't use FETCH the collections are not created but you can still use the JOIN attributes in you filter for example. But if you need the collection of articles and you don't do a fetch join the colleciton will be lazy loaded with a second request. 10 magazines you get 11 requests rather than one so it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alan Hay. The solution is simple we just need to use the Fetch keyword. In order to populate the collection.

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Folder f LEFT JOIN FETCH f.tags t WHERE
        f.id = :id")
Folder findFolderById(@Param("id") int id);
```